# google.youtube from the googleapi node-module is not a function?

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Good evening guys,
I'm trying to request the **Youtube API in node js** to get a video **JSON** from a string url.
I read the youtube api and it pretty much lead me to write the following code. Which isn't working because the **google.youtube isn't a function**. 
The main problem seems to be coming from the videosListById function. google.youtube is supposed to be imported from the **googleapi node module**, as shown in the api guide.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var readline = require("readline");
var google = require("googleapis");
var googleAuth = require("google-auth-library");

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/google-apis-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"];
var TOKEN_DIR = "src/google/.credentials/";
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + "google-api-tokens.json";

getYoutubeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zJ1b-atqpA");

function getYoutubeVideoId(url) {
  return url.split("=")[1];
}

// Load client secrets from a local file.
function getYoutubeVideo(url) {
  const _id = getYoutubeVideoId(url);
  fs.readFile("src/google/client_secret.json", function processClientSecrets(
    err,
    content
  ) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error loading client secret file: " + err);
      return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
    //See full code sample for authorize() function code.
    authorize(
      JSON.parse(content),
      {
        params: { id: _id, part: "snippet,contentDetails,statistics" }
      },
      videosListById
    );
  });
}

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, requestData, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new googleAuth.OAuth2Client(
    clientId,
    clientSecret,
    redirectUrl
  );

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, requestData, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client, requestData);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, requestData, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log("Authorize this app by visiting this url: ", authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question("Enter the code from that page here: ", function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error while trying to retrieve access token", err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client, requestData);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != "EEXIST") {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log("Token stored to " + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Remove parameters that do not have values.
 *
 * @param {Object} params A list of key-value pairs representing request
 *                        parameters and their values.
 * @return {Object} The params object minus parameters with no values set.
 */
function removeEmptyParameters(params) {
  for (var p in params) {
    if (!params[p] || params[p] == "undefined") {
      delete params[p];
    }
  }
  return params;
}

/**
 * Create a JSON object, representing an API resource, from a list of
 * properties and their values.
 *
 * @param {Object} properties A list of key-value pairs representing resource
 *                            properties and their values.
 * @return {Object} A JSON object. The function nests properties based on
 *                  periods (.) in property names.
 */
function createResource(properties) {
  var resource = {};
  var normalizedProps = properties;
  for (var p in properties) {
    var value = properties[p];
    if (p && p.substr(-2, 2) == "[]") {
      var adjustedName = p.replace("[]", "");
      if (value) {
        normalizedProps[adjustedName] = value.split(",");
      }
      delete normalizedProps[p];
    }
  }
  for (var p in normalizedProps) {
    // Leave properties that don't have values out of inserted resource.
    if (normalizedProps.hasOwnProperty(p) && normalizedProps[p]) {
      var propArray = p.split(".");
      var ref = resource;
      for (var pa = 0; pa < propArray.length; pa++) {
        var key = propArray[pa];
        if (pa == propArray.length - 1) {
          ref[key] = normalizedProps[p];
        } else {
          ref = ref[key] = ref[key] || {};
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return resource;
}

function videosListById(auth, requestData) {
  /*var service = google.youtube({
    version: "v3",
    auth: process.env.API_KEY
  });*/
  var service = google.youtube("v3");
  var parameters = removeEmptyParameters(requestData["params"]);
  parameters["auth"] = auth;
  service.videos.list(parameters, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I found the solution

```
var google = require("googleapis");
```

should have been

```
var {google} = require("googleapis");
```